# Problem with wallet.transfer in newer solidity compilers

Tags: address.transfer, compiler

I read the documentation of the changes on 0.5.0 but I do not know how to get this done with my code snippet. I tried to make the constructor payable but this does not work. Can someone help me. The line "wallet.transfer(msg.value) always through this error: "transfer" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in address" I know that something changed with the namespaces but I cannot figure out how to workaround

```
contract WalletFactory {
    mapping(address => address[]) wallets;

    function newWallet(address _owner) payable public returns(address wallet) {
        wallet = (address)(new createWallet(msg.sender));
        wallets[msg.sender].push(wallet);
        wallet.transfer(msg.value);
    }
}

contract createWallet {
    address public owner;

    constructor(address _owner) payable public {
        owner = _owner;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a few changes. Importantly, I added a payable fallback function to the `Wallet` contract (formerly called "createWallet"). (Otherwise it can't accept ether via `transfer`.) I also used the `Wallet` type everywhere possible rather than immediately casting to `address`. This is good for general type safety reasons.

```
pragma solidity 0.5.2;

contract WalletFactory {

    mapping(address => Wallet[]) wallets;

    function newWallet() payable public returns (Wallet wallet)
    {
        wallet = new Wallet(msg.sender);
        wallets[msg.sender].push(wallet);
        address(wallet).transfer(msg.value);
    }

}

contract Wallet {
    address public owner;
    constructor(address _owner) payable public {
        owner = _owner;
    }

    function() external payable { }
}
```